# Elasticsearch range request

Tags: php, curl, elasticsearch, range

I want to create a request that transmits me all the documents for last 15min.
My XPUT document looks like this:

```
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/indexname/documentname/4 -d'
{
    "user": "sergey",
    "onlineUserCount": "43"
}'
```

I've searched like this:

```
$ curl -XGET localhost:9200/indexname/documentname/_query -d'{
"query":{
  "range":{
    "timestamp":{
      "gt": "now -15m"
    }
  }
}}'
```

But It gave me

```
{"_index":"indexname","_type":"documentname","_id":"_query","found":false}
```

Help please!!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `_search` endpoint instead of the `_query` endpoint and it's more advisable to use -XPOST when sending a query in the HTTP request body.

```
$ curl -XPOST localhost:9200/indexname/documentname/_search -d'{
"query":{
  "range":{
    "timestamp":{
      "gt": "now -15m"
    }
  }
}}'
```

Comment: Is it possible get the same result without timestamp? I mean my documents timestamp disabled. how can i get data range without timestamp?

Comment: Do you have a date field in your documents that you can query?

Comment: No, I haven't nothing about date in my fields. I asked does elasticsearch create it authomaticly when timestamp disabled?

Comment: If you disable the [default `_timestamp` field](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-timestamp-field.html), I'm not aware of any other dates you can use.

Comment: curl -XPUT localhost:9200/indexname/documentname/4 -d'
{
    "user": "sergey",
    "onlineUserCount": "43"
}'

Comment: Last question how i can add timestamp enabled with current time with my XPUTcurl -XPUT localhost:9200/indexname/documentname/4 -d'
{
    "user": "sergey",
    "onlineUserCount": "43"
}'

Comment: You can simply enable the [default `_timestamp` field](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-timestamp-field.html) in your mapping.